# Is the defintion of paraxial rays related to the size of the lens?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I am not a optical engineer but the product I am working on contains on optical system, so I am learning optics on my own. Every book on optics has one chapter about paraxial rays.

*The commonly used optical expressions like the lens equation are approximations which are only valid for light rays close to the optic axis for which the approximation sinθ ≈ θ is valid. Such rays are called "paraxial rays".*

If the lens is small such as cameras on mobile phones, can all rays entering the lens be considered as paraxial rays?
FOVs of mini camera modules in mobile phones are currently 60-75 degree full. Does it mean most of rays entering the lens are marginal rays?
How does optical design software handle marginal rays? It seems that books on optics includes little information about processing marginal rays.

Comment: Mobile phones nowadays often use aspherical optics. Such designs are not in optics books that you would study on your own.

Comment: If you do want to build up to those systems, a good next-step-up-the-ladder starting point is to look up 'spherical aberration'.

Comment: I have a "Foldscope" which has a ball lens, but because of your question I found this smart trick to make a microscope: reversing a camera lens. Well explained with ray diagrams.  http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0095330

Comment: > Mobile phones nowadays often use aspherical optics. Such designs are not in optics books that you would study on your own. 

This is just not true aspherical lens' have been the standard for years and will be included in any semi-decent optics book.